# Insert an element inside a choice option to his 'father' everytime from a target mssage in mapping node

Tags: xml, xsd, mapping, esb, messagebroker

I am using a mapping node in my messageflow in IBM esb/wmb and there is a part where i need to insert a specific element from the target message to his "father" in the target message, this element is inside a 'choice' option.

For example:

```
<xs:element name="JOB">
     <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice>
           <xs:element name="YES"/>
           <xs:element name="NO"/>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

I want the 'JOB' element in the target message to always get the 'YES' element.

Is there any way to do this with some build function(s) in mapping node in wmb ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set static values by the assign function. Just right click on the target element and select Create Assign.